Crontab job for specific cron activity
I'm trying to setup the Job Scheduler so that specific actions can be checked against cron every minute to allow for publishing content on a scheduled basis.
I'm working on part of an Acquia Cloud setup and whilst I've seen that there is documentation about setting up custom jobs, I don't want every cron activity to run, only the job_scheduler_cron, but I don't know how to write the script to only run that code
I've got Ultimate Cron ready to go into a new release but that would have to be rolled into all of the active sites, is there a way of writing a crontab job that only looks for the 'job_scheduler_cron' instead of just modifying the standard Drupal one to once per minute?

drush ev 'job_scheduler_cron()'?

@Andy would that throw an error if the module is disabled though?

Yup. You can add a check to the code passed to drush ev if you want it to work on sites that might not have the module installed.
